# Mobile soft keyboard not updating via Ajax populated dropdown (when arrows used)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile, soft-keyboard

I have two select fields, Country and City:

```
    <select id="country" onchange="getCity(this);">
        <option value="">-- Please select your country --</option>
        <option value="1">Austria</option>
        <option value="2">Switzerland</option>
    </select>
    <select name="city" id="selectFormCity" onchange="setCity(this);">
        <option value="none">-- Please select --</option>
    </select>
```

When selecting a country the city dropdown will be populated via Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("country").onchange()
    function getCity(elem) {
        var v = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;

        new Ajax.Request('https://example.com/registration/index/getCity/', {
            parameters: {
                id: v},
            method:'get',
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
                var response = transport.responseText;
                $("selectFormCity").innerHTML(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This works perfectly on Desktop. I've tested various browsers and devices in Chrome emulator.

**But when I run this on a real phone (for example IOS) I'm facing following issue within the soft keyboard:**

When I click on the country dropdown, the mobile soft-keyboard shows up and I can scroll through the countries. When I do not close the keyboard by pressing the "Finish" button but want to use the "Arrows" to jump to the next form, the city dropdown keeps staying empty (although it was updated via Ajax). It does not get populated with the new data as long as the keyboard stays open.

**Questions**

1. Do anyone know how to "refresh" the 2nd dropdown when the arrows for navigation have been used? Without closing the keyboard?
2. Or do anyone know how to hide the arrows for navigating through the form?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**

It seems like a common issue:

[Example 1](http://demos.mitrajit.com/dynamic-dropdown-using-jquery-ajax-php/)

[Example 2](http://makitweb.com/auto-populate-dropdown-with-jquery-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You could prohibit the opening of the keyboard all together by setting the select to `readonly="true"`.
You could also try to set the focus for example on the document in your `onchange()` function. That should close the keyboard.